# Unable to edit or move text boxes

Tags: arcmap

I am running ArcMap 10.6.1 and I can not select, edit or move text boxes I have add to my map in layout view. I have several annotation labels in my map all of those I can select, edit and move. Is there something I am missing with the text boxes?

Comment: Have you closed and restarted ArcMap?

Comment: Is your data frame focused? (a toggle icon on the Layout toolbar) That simulates editing in Data View, which would permit moving data-linked annotation but not non-linked items.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to solve this kind of problem is, Close your ArcMap and ArcCatalog and go to your profile

> Users > user_name > AppData > Roaming > ESRI > Desktop > ArcCatalog/ArcMap

. Rename existing folder then re-open the ArcMAP and catalog.

This will restore default settings of your ArcMAP and ArcCatalog and all the problems should go away.